# Synchronizing nested subscribe in angular2

Tags: typescript, angular

I have the following code which logs : `"foo2"` and then `"foo1"`:

```
a() {
  b().then(() => {
     console.log("foo2")
  })
}

b() {
   return webServiceCall().do(() => {
      webServiceCall2().subscribe(() => {
         console.log("foo1")      
      })
   }) 
}
```

I would like to be sure that my `foo1` appears before my `foo2`.

How could I solve this issue ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can be sure that `foo1` appears before `foo2` if you use chained promises.

If the order of `webServiceCall1` and `webServiceCall2` matters:

```
b() {
    return webServiceCall1().then(() => {
        return webServiceCall2().then(() => {
            console.log("foo1")
        })
    })
}
```

If the order of `webServiceCall1` and `webServiceCall2` doesn't matter, use [Observable.forkJoin](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/forkjoin.md) :

```
b() {
    return Observable.forkJoin(webServiceCall1,webServiceCall2).toPromise().then(() => {
        console.log("foo1"); 
    });
}
```

Comment: Let's say I have webServiceCall3 also present inside my webServiceCall1 (being called just after webServiceCall2) then I have to move it inside webServiceCall2 the same way ? That will actually makes everything sequential.

Comment: Brilliant, but can a forkJoin take more than 2 parameters ? like if I have a webServiceCall3, can I do forkJoin(wSC1, wSC2, wSC3) ?

Comment: Yes, forkJoin can take more then 2 parameters. You can read it here: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/forkjoin.md